# Can I cut out the texture part of an object?

Tags: mesh, texturing, transparency

Hello to all members of this forum

**Project:**

I am currently working on the clothes of my character model. The cloth object is just a duplication of the body object with a transparent material (armor). For the modifier I used a Subsurf and Solidify modifier, so I don't get any vertices errors. At the end I combined these 2 objects via armature and generally I don't have a problem, but...

**To my Problem:**

the armor object in the way, when I am working on the material. As an example, if I want to add a few shaders like a Glass Shader, my transparent shader starts to bug around. An idea that occurred to me would be to just cut out the textured part of the object. Is this in any way possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using armature for both objects you can just hide one of them in the Outliner. If you joined objects together and didn't connect any of their vertices then you can easily assign different materials to them from edit mode. Go to edit mode, mouse over one of the objects, press L (it should select only connected vertices, 1 object in your case), assign other material to faces from material tab (Assign button under list of object materials).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The problem is, that the edges of the material are very pixelated and I don't know how to smooth it up.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rH-0MOAfKiYdZCjSx0f-aMt3rG72ujM_/view

Comment: I assume it's a part of your armor object and by "pixelated" you mean mesh doesn't have enough geometry to look smooth, you would need to up subdivision level on subsurf modifier (probably already set shading on object to smooth). If it's an actual "pixelating" from texture you are using then you would need to use better resolution for image texture or you can try smear/smooth tools in texture paint.